# Active status on comment flag

Tags: support, comment-flags, active

I [flagged a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/223277) and went to check on the status of the flag.

[image: active on flag]

What does active mean?

Comment: This is a new feature, that was implemented after I went to bed, it's morning here, so please don't downvote my question. The duplicate was posted 14 hours ago

Comment: What? You mean the first thing you do in the morning after waking up is not to read all of the Meta questions that got posted? For shame!

Comment: @CodyGray the first thing I do is check Meta and the last thing before I go to bed (how sick am I??) but I got caught up in some posts here and on SO, so hadn't got back to the front page and missed the recent dup.. shame on me, yes.. yes yes, I did a bad thing, very bad thing.. breaking one of the 1,643,902,461,770 social laws of Meta (ok I DO admit, perhaps the most vital - search first) but still.. heaven help the member who transgresses one of these laws.. and to think my is meta insane post got deleted.. shame on you, shame on you all *evil, slightly unhinged, laughter*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means that the flag hasn't been dismissed yet - no moderator has evaluated it and either declined or marked it as helpful.

Comment: but usually they sit there looking blank

Comment: is this a new feature, as my flags on SO are also showing active? They, usually, don't show that

Comment: Yes - it was changed to make it more obvious that the flag was still waiting to be handled. We've seen a bit of confusion there in the past, and I believe we were actually hiding these entirely in some places.

Comment: when did it change? don't worry saw that, so my question for 14 hours too late and I get a down vote.. for asking about a new feature

Comment: This was changed on Friday, @Skippy.