# Answering Duplicate questions in and then another Duplicate Question within the Comments

Tags: support, questions, comments, answers

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914985/1082944) a question. The question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210525/how-do-i-convert-hex-to-decimal-in-python), which I flagged.

The OP then asked this question via [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914917/convert-hex-value-to-decimal-value/17914985?noredirect=1#comment26171675_17914985). The comment question is also a [duplicate question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826054/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-16-x0e-xa3-python)

Is this the correct response?

[image: comments]

The issue with having a duplicate question in a comment within a duplicate question is:

How much time should I really spend on this, when there are perfectly good answers?

Comment: You don't have to answer follow-up questions - you have taken the correct action. The user should be asking a new question instead of asking a follow-up question. (this has been asked before, searching... Ah, found it! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: I think your response was wrong. If he tried using your code, and it didn't work, then he shouldn't have to ask an entirely new question

Comment: @Doorknob I did search for it, I mustn't use the right key words in my searches, as I frequently post duplicate questions that I have searched. Not sure how to change that.

Comment: @Skippy Well, the duplicate does have a very confusing name - chameleon? :P now that you've asked this, other people can find the other question easier. That's why we don't delete dups - because they're like signposts.

Comment: @CodyGuldner see my edit, it's not the usual case

Comment: @Doorknob sorry I lost my temper, I am really bad tempered and it's my biggest flaw. Not your fault (or anyone elses). I should've searched before I posted and it taught me a lesson.  And yes with the dups, I upvoted and flagged the one mentioned in THIS post, as I think it's a good question nevertheless and it's another signpost ;)

Comment: @Doorknob I don't think this is a dup, pls see the edit, I was going to put this in originally, but wanted to keep it simple, but in this case, I think it warrants another peek

Comment: @CodyGuldner: If you answer a question which fixes the original problem but leads to a new question, the OP should indeed post a new question.  The problems may not be related, and the person who helped with the answer may not even be able to help.  They answered because they knew the answer to the first (original) question, not the second one!

Comment: @lnafziger yes I agree, sometimes it can be thrashed out in the comments, byt my experience has been like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708974/chart-show-more-value-descriptions-on-x-axis

Comment: @Skippy Hmm, I think simply posting the links woul be the easiest way. (and don't worry about that other question - I've seen far worse :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion which would have kept you from having this issue in the first place:  If you know that a question is a duplicate, rather than answering it, simply vote to close as a duplicate question (or flag it as a duplicate if you don't have the reputation) and move on.  This points other people who find the question as well as the OP to the correct answer.

For more advice on how to handle duplicates, see:
[Should I answer the question which is the duplicate of another question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118658/226446)
and the faq:
[How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/226446)

Comment: I don't believe the OP has enough rep to vote-to-close.

Comment: @chuex yes that is correct

Comment: @lnafziger that is NOT a solution see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190787/active-status-on-comment-flag plenty of dup questions are answered and by highly rep users ps I thought your name started with an i and couldn't link you ;)

Comment: Actually, it is, IF there are already good answers in the duplicate.  See:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/226446.  "StackExchange sites exist to provide answers to questions and duplicate questions are no exception. **However, the asker will probably be better served by reviewing the existing answers to the question they duplicated and should be directed to it in comments. Duplicate questions are also likely to be closed and/or deleted potentially negating any reputation gained from answers to them.**"

Comment: @Skippy: Yeah, a lot of people start my username with an `i` instead of an `l`, so you aren't alone there, lol.  :-)

Comment: @inafziger: Really? That's weird, I wonder who would do that... :P (@lnafgizer)